# Using wget to download image from url pointing to jpg

Tags: http, command-line, terminal, console, wget

I have a link pointing to a `.jpg`: https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/nature-sunset-simple-minimal-illustration_am1ramqUmZqaraWkpJRnamtlrWZpaWU.jpg

I'm trying to download it using `wget https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/nature-sunset-simple-minimal-illustration_am1ramqUmZqaraWkpJRnamtlrWZpaWU.jpg`

I am getting:

```
Connecting to images.wallpapersden.com (images.wallpapersden.com)|104.26.8.233|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-12-22 05:24:31 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I'm assuming I'm not using `wget` correctly, or need to use some other cli tool?

--Update--

I've just learned that I can use `curl` to download the image e.g `curl url/to/image.jpg > saveas.jpg`, but I'm still curious if there's anyway to do this with `wget`?

Comment: The error I get is quite different: `Connecting to images.wallpapersden.com|104.26.8.233|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Unable to establish SSL connection.
`

Answer (score 1):

> I've just learned that I can use `curl` to download the image e.g
> `curl url/to/image.jpg > saveas.jpg`, but I'm still curious if there's
> anyway to do this with `wget`?

I run few test regarding `https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/nature-sunset-simple-minimal-illustration_am1ramqUmZqaraWkpJRnamtlrWZpaWU.jpg` and it seems to blacklist `wget`. When making HTTP request [`User-Agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header is used to inform what tool made said request.

`wget` has `--user-agent` which allow supplying User-Agent, so wget appear as something else to server, for example to impostor Firefox version 47 do

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0" https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/nature-sunset-simple-minimal-illustration_am1ramqUmZqaraWkpJRnamtlrWZpaWU.jpg
```

`wget`'s [`man` page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html) gives following rationale for this ability

> ```
>        The HTTP protocol allows the clients to identify themselves
>        using a "User-Agent" header field.  This enables
>        distinguishing the WWW software, usually for statistical
>        purposes or for tracing of protocol violations.  Wget
>        normally identifies as Wget/version, version being the
>        current version number of Wget.
>
>        However, some sites have been known to impose the policy of
>        tailoring the output according to the "User-Agent"-supplied
>        information.  While this is not such a bad idea in theory, it
>        has been abused by servers denying information to clients
>        other than (historically) Netscape or, more frequently,
>        Microsoft Internet Explorer.  This option allows you to
>        change the "User-Agent" line issued by Wget.  Use of this
>        option is discouraged, unless you really know what you are
>        doing.
>
>        Specifying empty user agent with --user-agent="" instructs
>        Wget not to send the "User-Agent" header in HTTP requests.
> ```